# Android, Layout clicklistener and subview click through problem

Tags: android, layout, view, click

I have a RelativeLayout to which I add buttons and set their onCLickListener to the current Activity where I handle their clicks.

Under a particular circumstance I need to set the RelativeLayout onClickListener also, but then once finished with the required clicking on the layout, I need to allow clicking on the buttons again. (i.e. clicking throug hthe layout)

If I set the layout's click listener to null I can no longer click either the layout or the buttons that are it's child views.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: I seem to have fixed it by setting;**

```
relativeLayout.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: just use boolean flag to do that

Comment: That's no help, I need to set the Layout onCLickListener regardless, I then need to "unset" it at a certain point in time later. So that I can click through it to child views (which earlier was prevented by the onClickListener).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(null);
relativeLayout.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
```

?

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by adding relativeLayout.setClickable(false);

Comment: These kind of problems are usually down to descendant focusability, some degree of playing with various focusability and click settings should sort it out.